# Firebase SDK 9.0.0 plain java version?

Tags: java, javafx, firebase

Firebase SDK 9.0.0 is exciting but I cannot find the plain java version of its library. The [older 2.5.2 doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html) used to have separate SDK for Android and plain JVM, I cannot find this information in the [new doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Is there a way to use this SDK for non-Android project, like say, JavaFX? If not, will I run into a problem for still using the older 2.5.2 SDK on my JavaFX project?

Comment: I have a work around for using it in a non-android JVM here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46199214/3731335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Look under [Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) in the docs instead of the Android section.

> We publish the Firebase Java SDK to the Maven central repository. To
>   install the library, you can simply declare it as a dependency in your
>   build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)'
> }
> ```
>
> If you use Maven
>   to build your application, you can add the following dependency to
>   your pom.xml:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
>     <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
>     <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: Please note that the server SDK uses a Google service account and would not be appropriate for a JavaFX client. You can't distribute that.