# How to use firebase with javafx

Tags: javafx, firebase

am building a desktop application that I want to use the intuitive firebase API for live data syncs. I have been searching the web but no one points out what Jars to use and how to configure with your firebase application. If you can assist please give me steps. I am good at following steps. I want to create a helper class for all firebase operations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase SDK 9.0.0 plain java version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455308/firebase-sdk-9-0-0-plain-java-version)

Comment: No, I checked that link and I cannot get what I want. Sorry I might sound lazy but am doing something urgent thats why am posting a question here. I was wondering if I could get a sample code of how to initialize and or use firebase with java with pointers of where to download the jars

Comment: You can download it from Maven. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-server-sdk/3.0.0

Comment: And the getting started guide is here https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_the_sdk

Comment: Yea I have seen the getting started guide. Where do you get the "serviceAccountCredentials.json" in the sample code:

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

Comment: You download it from the firebase console as specified in this section https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Comment: Thank you @eikooc You are really helpful.

Comment: Could you probably write a small steps instruction for getting started. I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is risky to use the admin SDK on a client machine because it has admin rights to your database. I have developed a work around by creating a WebEngine that will read a html file that has no body just the firebase web scripts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>`
<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
    try {
        var config = {
          //firebase config here
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        var data = firebase.database();
        var ref = data.ref("/ref");
        ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
            //pass snapshot to java
            alert(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
        });
    } catch (error) {
        alert("Error - jse:" + error.message);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

and to retrieve it in java

```
    //Start new webengine to run javascript.
    final WebEngine engine = new WebEngine();
    //get my html file.
    final URL url = NoficationTest.class.getResource("/javafx.html");
    //set to catch alerts from the javascript.
    engine.setOnAlert(event -> {
        try {

            final String data = event.getData();
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.contains("jse")) {
                      //handle if error in javascript.
                } else {
                      //handle if successfull
                }
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    //Load html into webengine.
    engine.load(url.toString());
```

There is a better way for the javascript to call the java side of things, I just did it that way to have a fast answer. I have tested this and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps from https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup

Which can be broken down into:

- Create a firebase project
- Download the SDK from Maven
- Download the service account file which you can create from the web interface
- Add the SDK
- Initialize the SDK

I think the problem is that it is easy to overlook some of the steps on the website. Just follow them *step by step* and read carefully what steps are listed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST Api for accessing database as well as authentication.
Check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37419212/5287436