# Using Firebase Storage in server

Tags: java, firebase, storage

I learned from [past thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455308/firebase-sdk-9-0-0-plain-java-version/37456232#37456232) that Firebase Database for plain JVM can be accessed from the new [server SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup). So now I could use Firebase Database SDK for my JavaFX project, but how do I use the Storage SDK?

Sadly, [Firebase Storage doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) doesn't mention anything about setting up storage in server. [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) is also not available from `com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)` or `com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.1`.

Comment: So were you successful in implementing firebase storage in server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase Storage does not have a server SDK, but because it's backed by Google Cloud Storage, you can use the GCS server SDKs. Here are the [GCS docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples) for accessing it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

In the Gradle File add `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.7.0'` 
or [latest java library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java)

If the Storage url is say `gs://some-bucket-name.appspot.com/directory/some_blob.zip` then STORAGE_BUCKET must be `some-bucket-name.appspot.com`
and path should be `directory/some_blob.zip`

```
private long getSize(String path) {

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
            .setProjectId(STORAGE_BUCKET)
            // Optionally Add credentials
            //.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonFile)))
            .build()
            .getService();

    // Optional third parameter to limit fields returned, just getting size for my use case
    Blob blob = storage.get(STORAGE_BUCKET, path, Storage.BlobGetOption.fields(Storage.BlobField.SIZE));
    if (blob != null) {
        return blob.getSize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```